# Django : How to rate-limit POSTS from same IP or user?

Tags: django, webserver

Is there a built in way or some apps to do it in Django?

For example limit number of comments a user can post on a per hour basis ? Something to protect my site from a malicious flood of POSTs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ways to tackle this -

1. There are `modules` for webservers which track requests per IP basis, you could set a limit there stating that if requests from a particular IP exceed a limit, then stop serving request for some pre-defined time period (a.k.a. blacklist)
2. Instead of blocking, you can be more gentle & show a CAPTCHA.

So this decision making essentially should be handled well before Django comes into the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using existing framework like django.contrib.comments or you use self-made comments?

If you use contrib.comments, you can drop comment posting on receiving signal comment_will_be_posted ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/comments/signals/#comment-will-be-posted ).

If you don't know how to use signals framework in django, read this link: "docs djangoproject com" -> "Other batteries included" -> "Signals" (sorry for such explanation, i can't post more than one link).

Comment: It is not just for comments. It should protect for any kind of stuff gets submitted by users

Comment: well, use signals framework, send signals from your custom submit functions and read documentation about built-in submit functions.

Answer (score 0):

try with [ReCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) to prevent flood or spam

Answer (score -3):

Are you using an existing framework? (i.e. Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress). Those platforms may have plugins or extensions that would do what you want.

There are a couple of ways you can accomplish POST protection.

1.) Every time someone submits a form, store a cookie on their computer with date and time of the POST. Then on every post check to see if that cookie exists and when the last time they posted was. Deny or accept the post based on the time frame.

2.) Create a DB table that stores the POST data, the IP address of the person who submitted it, and the date of the submission. On every POST, first check the database for the same IP address within the specified date range. Deny or accept the post.

3.) You can always integrate a Captcha, since most spammers use automated scripts to post to forms.

[Swhistle Soft](http://www.swhistlesoft.com)